# MVC Run a Stored Procedure to Export to Excel outside entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a list in a table and I use that list to display a list of reports I can generate by clicking on the export button - I then want the export button to take the question code and export the stored procedure output to excel.

I can't use entity framework as I use 1 stored procedure and each Question Code generates a different set of columns

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Export(string QCode = "")
    {

        if (QCode != "")
        {
            GridView gv = new GridView() { AutoGenerateColumns = true };
            // Run Stored Procedure Code Not using Entity Framework
            gv.DataSource = StoredProcedure(QCode).ToList();

            gv.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExportQuestion_" + QCode + ".xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gv.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        public ActionResult Export(string QCode = "")
    {

        if (QCode != "")
        {
            GridView gv = new GridView() { AutoGenerateColumns = true };
            string strSQL = "GetExcelExtract '" + QCode + "'";
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
            SqlCommand SQLCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, SQLConn);
            SQLCmd.CommandTimeout = 90;
            SqlDataAdapter SQlAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SQlAdpt.SelectCommand = SQLCmd;
            SQLConn.Open();
            SQlAdpt.Fill(DS);
            SQLConn.Close();


            gv.DataSource = DS;
            gv.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExportQuestion_" + QCode + ".xls");
            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gv.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

        }
        return View();
    }
```

I got it in the end - hope it helps!